# MDRIVEN | ContextAgent in VS 2019

Tags: mdriven

Unable to access Context Agent in VS 2019 with the latest MDriven Framework.

Has it been removed or there is any way to bring it inside VS 2019?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Context Agent was part of the MDriven Framework visual studio plugin until 2019 builds. It was removed as it represents the older strategy of placing handle components on windows forms.

The modern way of working is to declare ViewModels in Modlr and bind to these.

A much more effecient way to track the model usage is to use the ViewModels with CodeGen-box checked and then bind to the generated information structure from the UI controls - thus skipping the handles all together.